# comboBox C#, SelectedText vs SelectedItem.ToString()

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox

Qual a diferença entre os dois?
Os valores podem ser diferentes ocorrer um erro por causa disso?
Qual ocupa mais memoria?

Aparentemente os dois retornam o mesmo valor, mas gostaria de tirar essa duvida para evitar futuras "surpresas"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O primeiro citado, [`ComboBox.SelectedItem`](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.combobox.selecteditem?view=net-5.0) retorna um `Object` de texto se tiver um item selecionado lá, ou `null` se não houver algum item selecionado no controle.

Já o [`ComboBox.SelectedText`](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.combobox.selectedtext?view=net-5.0) retornará uma `String` com o texto do item selecionado. Se for nulo, virá vazio (`""`), e se a propriedade `DropDownStyle` for `DropDownList`, ele retornará sempre como vazio.

Neste caso, o `SelectedText` é útil para quando o controle está em modo de texto escrito, e quando é lista, convém usar o `SelectedItem`.

Answer (score 0):

A propriedade SelectedText retorna ou altera o texto selecionado no comboBox. O tipo de Retorno dele é uma string. Já a propriedade SelectedItem retorna ou altera o Item do ComboBox.O tipo de retorno dele é um object. Por isso você precisa utilizar o método toString() para apresentar o texto selecionado no  SelectedItem. O objetivo do SelectedItem é permitir que vocÊ armazene objetos complexos no comboBox e possa sobrescrever o método toString deste objeto para apresentar qualquer outro tipo de valor representativo do item selecionado no combobox.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.combobox?view=net-5.0